# Save and extract data of HTTP request to database

Tags: jmeter

I want to save and extract the data of HTTP POST and GET request to database(SQL Server).

How to achieve in JMeter? Please help me.

Comment: Did you bother trying anything before asking?

Comment: I tried JDBC configuration and successfully get result for select query but I don't know how to use it with Http post method.

Comment: In the JDBC request, there is an option "variable names" which holds the values returned from the query. then you can use these variables with your post request

Answer (score 0):

Take the following steps to store the data from [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler into the database:

1. First of all you need to save the data into a JMeter Variable. According to the [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter) article you would need the following [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) configuration:

   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `responseData`
   - Regular Expression: `(?s)(^.*)`
   - Template: `$1$`
2. Add [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler and configure it as follows:

   - Variable Name: matching the one you set in the [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration)
   - Query Type: `Update Statement`
   - Query: `INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(${responseData})` (you will need to amend this query according to your database schema, the `${responseData}` JMeter Variable will be holding the result of the HTTP Request sampler execution.